# Evaluating SQL-query to LINQ-object - C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dynamic SQL string which I want to evaluate and return as a LINQ-object.

Is there any easy way to do this in C#? Have tried googleing it, but haven't found anything.. So all(or most) answers are appreciated.

Best Regards,
Robin

Comment: LINQ object ? pls elaborate..

Comment: LINQ to SQL.. But instead of selecting from data classes, it selects from a recordset. Or is it maybe possible to turn a recordset into a enumerable LINQ-object? (using LINQ to object?)

Comment: you mean you want to convert an SQL query to the appropriate LINQ query?

Comment: No, I want to make an SQL query (from a dynamic string variable) and then have the result in a Linq object.

Comment: It is possible to do LINQ to Object for a DataSet or RecordSet?

Comment: Yes... It is called LINQ to DataSet. http://language-integrated-query.com/Linq_to_Dataset.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> linq;
linq = (IEnumerable<XElement>)XElement.Parse(RawXmlData.ToString()).Elements();
```